# Running on device using IPv6 causes app to crash

Tags: ios, swift, audio, swift2, playback

I tried to submit a sound app for iPad and iPhone (iOS 9.3.5). Then I was told that my play button would not play audio when pressed when connect to a IPv6. This was the code I used to start and stop the sound. It works how I intended when running the simulator.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    var player1 = AVAudioPlayer()
func playsound(sender: AnyObject){

        let soundUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("fsfa", withExtension: "mp3")! // or m4a

        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            player1 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundUrl)
            player1.numberOfLoops = -1
            player1.prepareToPlay()
            player1.play()
        } catch _ {
            return print("sound file not found")
        }


    }
  func stopsound1(sender: AnyObject){
        let soundUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("dsd", withExtension: "mp3")!
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            player1 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundUrl)


            player1.stop()
        } catch _ {
            return print("sound file not found")
        }


    }
```

Comment: What crash are you getting?

Comment: It just says when the app runs on a 9.3.5 target audio does not play when it is pressed. It works perfectly on a 9.0 target. I guess the app just crashes and returns to home screen.

Comment: Try running the app on your own device and check what crash it is.

Comment: There's nothing related to IPv6 in this part of code.

Comment: Apple has made certain changes to iOS in the 9.3.5 update and that is causing app developers a lot of problems. So I am guessing your issue is related to that. I have that problem too and I am just having a read of the link below to see how I can test my app on IPv6.
http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-test-your-app-for-ipv6-compatibility/